# Telegram bot python

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, python-3.6, telebot

Запустил бота через командную строку ,пишу боту но он не чего не отвечает

[image: коммандная строка]

[image: бот]

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token="")
@bot.message_handler(comands=["start"])

def first (message):
    key = telebot.types.ReplayKeyboardMarkup (True,False)
    key.row("Кнопка 1", "Кнопка 2")
```

Answer (score 1):

Код должен выглядеть так

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot()

@bot.message_handler(commands = ['start']) #commands
def first(message):
    key = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, False) #Reply
    key.row("Кнопка 1", "Кнопка 2")
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Текст", reply_markup = key)
```

Во-первых, исправлены ошибки, помеченные комментариями

Во-вторых, необходимо отправить клавиатуру через сообщение с аргументом reply_markup